# When I try to use Hibernate ogm and spring boot the console gives "Could not instantiate named strategy class" error

Tags: spring, mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-ogm

I tried to connect hibernate ogm,Spring boot and mongodb.I used jpa for my development. So I selected Hibernate ogm... When I try to run the application the console gives below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:467) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1617) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1483) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:904) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:336) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:591) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:319) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Could not instantiate named strategy class [org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    ... 89 common frames omitted

25-Apr-2018 10:25:28.629 SEVERE [http-nio-8442-exec-204] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/tradeportal]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1483)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:336)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
```

I used org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider... I think the error is in application.yaml... *I cannot understand what is the database-platform under the spring.jpa*. I used **org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect** as a database-platform.But it gives an error

My pom.xml is

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--handle servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<Email Dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>      
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--jasper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web-services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.security/wss4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-libs</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.mongojdbcdriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongojdbcdriver</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Beta4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Application.yaml is

```
spring:
  main:
    web-environment: true
    banner-mode: console

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect

    hibernate:
      ogm: 
        datastore:
            database-platform: org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect
            provider: org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider
            host: http://127.0.0.1/
            port: 27017
            database: trade_portal_db
            create_database: true

  application:
    name: tradeportal
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: net.sf.mongodb_jdbc_driver.MongoDbDriver
    url: jdbc:mongo://127.0.0.1:27017/trade_portal_db

  http:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 5MB
      max-request-size: 25MB
server:
  port: 8080
  context-path: /tradeportal
tradeportalgov:
  reportData: /reports/images
  # if file path is given relative to the webapp base use INTERNAL if the absolute path is given to baseLocation use EXTERNAL
  # EXTERNAL file download is not implemented
  filePathType : INTERNAL
  filePaths:
    baseLocation: uploads_tradeportal
    vat: vat
    brc: brc
```

Spring-boot configuration is

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "lk.tradeportal")
@EnableWebMvc
@ImportResource(locations = "classpath:tradeportal-servlet-config.xml")
public class TRADEPORTALStarter extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger slsiLogger = LogManager.getLogger(TRADEPORTALStarter.class);

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        slsiLogger.info("Starting application");
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(TRADEPORTALStarter.class);
        context = application.run(args);
        application.setRegisterShutdownHook(true);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private static void closeAppContext(){
        context.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TRADEPORTALStarter.class);
    }
```

What is the error in my application

Answer (score 1):

The version of OGM you are using (`4.0.0.Beta4`) is way too old considering the version of Hibernate ORM you are using (`5.0.11.Final`). You should use compatible versions, because OGM depends on Hibernate ORM.

If you want to use ORM `5.0.11.Final`, then you should use OGM `5.0.4.Final`.
I would recommend upgrading to more recent versions, though; 5.0 is already one year and a half old and several versions have been published since it was first released.

Be careful though, the version number of OGM generally does not match the version number of ORM.
For compatibility of more recent versions of OGM with ORM, see http://hibernate.org/ogm/releases/#compatibility-matrix.

Comment: Ok.I will upgrade to recent version. But I wont to know how it configure... Is it want to any dialect class

Comment: There is documentation for each version to help you configuring everything. See http://hibernate.org/ogm/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Spring Boot but JBoss WildFly 11/12 with MongoDB. I had problems getting started. By ensuring I was using the latest version of Hibernate, OGM & Elastic Search etc. fixed it for me.

From your log:

> Caused by: java.lang.**NoSuchMethodException**:
>   org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect.()

Shows mismatch of version numbers.